# JavaFX alert dialog ignores the focused button

Tags: javafx, alert

Why does the JavaFX alert dialog fires the Platform.exit(); when I press the Enter key even though the focused button in the alert dialog is Cancel?

```
soaStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() 
{
    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent event) 
    {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Confirm");
        alert.setHeaderText("Are you sure you want to exit?");
        alert.setContentText("Press OK to exit, or Cancel to stay.");
        alert.initOwner(soaStage);

        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK)
        {
            Platform.exit();
        } 
        else 
        {
            event.consume();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I believe that to activate the focused button you have to press space. This is true (I think) not only for Java/JavaFX. For example in Windows native prompts, I use tab to quickly navigate and space to activate the selected button, not Enter. This is from my experience though, I do not know if it is an established guideline.

Comment: i guess you're right, but I just tried the MessageBoxButtons.YesNo in C#, we can activate a focused button by either the Enter key or Space.

Comment: I see. My comment was more of a personal view, for whatever it is worth. Read it as "**I**, as a user, press space to activate the focused button, not enter".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Default buttons are fired on <kbd>enter</kbd>**

The OK button is fired when you press <kbd>enter</kbd> because it is a [default button](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html#defaultButtonProperty).

> A default Button is the button that receives a keyboard VK_ENTER press, if no other node in the scene consumes it.

In the default JavaFX 8 Modena stylesheet, the default button is indicated by being a blue color rather than than the gray color of a standard button.

**How to remove default button behaviour**

You can remove this behavior from the alert dialog by not making the OK button a default button:

```
Button okButton = (Button) alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);
okButton.setDefaultButton(false);
```

*I advise you not to do this, but instead to always leave a default button in alert dialogs.*

On OS X, standard alert type dialogs have a default button which is triggered by <kbd>enter</kbd> even if another button is focused, so the standard behavior in JavaFX is consistent with that.  Note: to allow this behavior in default dialogs in OS X it is necessary to [enable full keyboard access](https://superuser.com/questions/473143/how-to-tab-between-buttons-on-an-mac-os-x-dialog-box).

If you do change the OK button to not be a default button, I suggest you change its text to something else (e.g. Exit for your case):

```
okButton.setText("Exit");
```

**How to make <kbd>enter</kbd> fire focused buttons**

Now, if you also want to make it so that the focused button fires when you press <kbd>enter</kbd>, then you can do this:

```
EventHandler<KeyEvent> fireOnEnter = event -> {
    if (KeyCode.ENTER.equals(event.getCode()) 
            && event.getTarget() instanceof Button) {
        ((Button) event.getTarget()).fire();
    }
};

DialogPane dialogPane = alert.getDialogPane();
dialogPane.getButtonTypes().stream()
        .map(dialogPane::lookupButton)
        .forEach(button ->
                button.addEventHandler(
                        KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,
                        fireOnEnter
                )
        );
```

Note: In any case, focused buttons are always fired when you press <kbd>space</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

We can add <kbd>ENTER</kbd> binding to the whole buttons by creating a class that need to be instantiated once when the application starts.

```
public class EnableButtonEnterKey extends ButtonBehavior<Button> {
    public EnableButtonEnterKey() {
        super(new Button());
        BUTTON_BINDINGS.add(new KeyBinding(ENTER, KEY_PRESSED, "Press"));
        BUTTON_BINDINGS.add(new KeyBinding(ENTER, KEY_RELEASED, "Release"));
    }
}
```

When starting the application, call

```
new EnableButtonEnterKey();
```

That's it.